# Textures in OpenGL show up as single colors?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures

I'm following this tutorial for using OpenGL https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures and everything was going great until I got to textures when for some reason instead of giving me the texture I expected, it seems to just give me a blank beige rectangle and I'm not sure why.

I tried several variations and eventually resorted to just copying the source code provided on the site https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/4.1.textures/textures.cpp and the problem still persisted. Why am I getting just a beige rectangle instead of the correct picture?

Here's what I expect:

[image]

Here's what I get:

[image]

Here's the code: (you can find `stb_image.h` [here](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h)

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

#include "shader_s.h"

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    Shader ourShader("./shaders/shader.vs", "./shaders/shader.fs"); 

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        // positions          // colors           // texture coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {  
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    // texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


    // load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); // all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    // The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("./resources/textures/container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);


    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // bind Texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        // render container
        ourShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

shader_s.h:

```cpp
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Shader
{
public:
    unsigned int ID;
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try 
        {
            // open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode   = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure& e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESSFULLY_READ: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessary
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
    }
    // activate the shader
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void use() 
    { 
        glUseProgram(ID); 
    }
    // utility uniform functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
    {         
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value); 
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
    { 
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value); 
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
    { 
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value); 
    }

private:
    // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void checkCompileErrors(unsigned int shader, std::string type)
    {
        int success;
        char infoLog[1024];
        if (type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

shader.vs:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    texCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

shader.fs

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

And the texture image: https://learnopengl.com/img/textures/container.jpg

The directory structure:

```
main.cpp
stb_image.h
shader_s.h
resources/textures/
  container.jpg
shaders/
  shader.fs
  shader.vs
```

I can't give you the glad headers/source, they're machine dependent, but there's a tutorial for installing them on the same site: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window

I know the site is geared towards doing this stuff in windows with VS, but I've been doing it all in linux, and so far it was all working great, until now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the texture coordinates, which do not arrive correctly in the fragment shader and are (0, 0) for each fragment. glsl is case-sensitive, and the output of the vertex shader is linked to the input of the fragment shader by its name. While the name of the output variable for the texture coordinates in your vertex shader is `texCoord`,

```c
out vec2 texCoord;
```

the name of the corresponding input variable for the texture coordinates in your fragment shader is `TexCoord`

```c
in vec2 TexCoord;
```

Change the fragment shader and rename `TexCoord` to `texCoord`:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, texCoord);
}
```